# Getting huge error spew from GtkD on a simple program

Tags: d, gdc, gtkd

I installed GtkD from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gtkd/), and now I'm trying to compile [this tutorial code](https://sites.google.com/site/gtkdtutorial/#chapter2). Both for compiling GtkD itself and the tutorial code, I'm using GDC 4.9.1.

I attempted to compile the code as follows (`hello.d` is the file name):

```
gdc -Wall -Werror -Wdeprecated -Wunknown-pragmas -g -m64 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkd-2` -O3 -frelease -o hello
```

But when I try that, I get *this*:

```
/tmp/ccxejYOB.o: In function `_Dmain':
/home/koz/Documents/Programming/D/gtkd/hello.d:23: undefined reference to `_D3gtk4Main4Main4initFKAAyaZv'
/home/koz/Documents/Programming/D/gtkd/hello.d:24: undefined reference to `_D3gtk10MainWindow10MainWindow7__ClassZ'
/home/koz/Documents/Programming/D/gtkd/hello.d:24: undefined reference to `_D3gtk10MainWindow10MainWindow6__ctorMFAyaZC3gtk10MainWindow10MainWindow'
/home/koz/Documents/Programming/D/gtkd/hello.d:26: undefined reference to `_D3gtk5Label5Label7__ClassZ'
/home/koz/Documents/Programming/D/gtkd/hello.d:26: undefined reference to `_D3gtk5Label5Label6__ctorMFAyabZC3gtk5Label5Label'
/home/koz/Documents/Programming/D/gtkd/hello.d:28: undefined reference to `_D3gtk4Main4Main3runFZv'
/tmp/ccxejYOB.o:(.data+0x30): undefined reference to `_D3gtk10MainWindow12__ModuleInfoZ'
/tmp/ccxejYOB.o:(.data+0x38): undefined reference to `_D3gtk5Label12__ModuleInfoZ'
/tmp/ccxejYOB.o:(.data+0x40): undefined reference to `_D3gtk4Main12__ModuleInfoZ'
/tmp/ccxejYOB.o:(.data._D67TypeInfo_S3std8typecons35__T6scopedTC5cairo7Context7ContextZ6Scoped6__initZ[_D67TypeInfo_S3std8typecons35__T6scopedTC5cairo7Context7ContextZ6Scoped6__initZ]+0x58): undefined reference to `_D3std8typecons35__T6scopedTC5cairo7Context7ContextZ6Scoped6__dtorMFZv'
```

I have *no clue* what's going on here, and would appreciate all the help possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GtkD undefined reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863213/gtkd-undefined-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GtkD in the AUR is compiled using DMD. ABI compatibility between DMD and GDC binaries is not guaranteed and linking may fail as in your case. (Linking may also succeed and you get runtime problems). To troubleshoot the issue, you can try using DMD and see if that solves your issue.

Anyway, I would recommend using [dub](http://code.dlang.org/download) and [gtk-d](http://code.dlang.org/packages/gtk-d) library from the dub registry. Dub will take care of the compilation of your source code and gtk-d's code and linking them together. And it will enable you to use any compiler easily.

If you don't want to use `dub`, you can also download [gtk-d](http://gtkd.org/) and build it yourself using GDC.